# Get all inputs from a submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has no id, no class whatsoever. I need to get all the inputs that are inside it, I have a script but it will get all inputs no matter if they are inside my form or not.

Of course I could add classes, id's to my forms but is there any way of doing what I want without adding identifiers to my form?

It is only logical that in my case it will iterate trough every input on my page, but how can I make sure it will only iterate trough every input on current form?

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input, textarea').each(function(){
        alert('a'); // Alerts on every input, not just inside this form...
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsN43/

Comment: Bruv - does this suits you, let me know will set it as answer: http://jsfiddle.net/qMS7P/31/, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `this` as context (second parameter) to jQuery function to search only inside current element.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input, textarea', this).each(function(){
        alert('a'); // Alerts on every input inside this form.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
        alert('a'); // Alerts on every input, just inside this form
    });
});
```

Comment: Although I prefer using context (like Mateusz W), this works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method like this: (it's better for debugging to print the tagName / name attributes of your elements, to make sure you find the right ones)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
            alert(this.nodeName + ' ' + $(this).attr('name'));
        });
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsN43/4/)